# Printing lists with __str__ and __repr__ in Python

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class Player which puts created objects in a List:

```
class Player:
    all = []
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        Player.all.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"N: {self.name}"
```

I wanted to print the list of the following objects using **repr**:

```
player1 = Player("p1")
player2 = Player("p2")
player3 = Player("p3")

print(Player.all)
```

I got what i was expecting:
`[N: p1, N: p2, N: p3]`
Printing the same list using **str**,

```
    def __str__(self):
        return f"N: {self.name}"
```

gave me this:
`[<classes.Player object at 0x00000213939B1AF0>, <classes.Player object at 0x00000213939B1AC0>, <classes.Player object at 0x00000213939B1B80>]`

But printing only one object, instead of the list, using **str** gave me something usable again:
`print(player1)`
`N: p1`

From what i understand, i can only print lists by using **repr**.
But, why?

Comment: As an aside, I consider using a class to track its own instances a bit of an anti-pattern. If something *else* needs a list of `Player` instances, it can maintain the list itself, including *removing* objects from the list when appropriate. Let `Player` focus on defining the behavior of individual instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list`s don't have a `str` form separate from their `repr` form (any class that implements `__repr__` but not `__str__` uses the `__repr__` when `__str__` is needed), and their `repr` form recursively prints the `repr` of the contained objects. `repr` makes sense for `list`s; if all the objects involved implement a canonical `repr` (one which can be pasted back into an interpreter to reproduce an equivalent object, unlike the form you're using<sup>†</sup>), then the `repr` of the `list` itself can also be pasted back in to reproduce it.

`str` form is not nearly so obvious; there's no single obvious "human-friendly" (as opposed to programmer-friendly) display format for a `list`, so Python [refuses the temptation to guess](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) and leaves it up to you to format the content of `list`s for human-friendly display as you like.

---

<sup>†</sup> The canonical `repr` for your class would be:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.name!r})"
```